# checking system timestamp with firestore's offline stored timestamp in background?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

Is there any way to check system timestamp with the cached firestore data's date and when the timestamps match a notification should be shown to user. even when the app is not running?

also how to query firestore's offline data?

I am new to android so please help.

Edited:-

I have tried this code and it shows a notification successfully if the user is in the app or using the app, but as soon as user leaves the app or switches to another app it don't show any notification.

```html
firestore.collection("abc").document("xyz").collection("validity").whereEqualTo("Date",Timestamp.now())
        .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override

    public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {

        //show notification

    }
});
```

basically i want a user to notifiy exactly on the time or like before a day when his validity expires so that he can renew it.

Comment: Sure there is. Have you tried something so far?

Comment: I have tried Quering the document to check the stored timestamp with current one from server side data. It works fine when I am using the app or app is running in foreground but as soon as the app is killed it stops listening. I don't know how to query the local cached data. so i am currently stuck there.

Comment: Please add that code to your question and indicate what doesn't work exactly the way you expect.